# Is it possible to create an air pump from leaf blower?

Tags: aquarium

Can I make an aquarium air pump from a leaf blower, to aerate all my aquariums at once ?

I am planning to cover the output of the blower with a pvc end-cap (holes drilled in) and run air line tubing to the aquariums from the holes. Will this be efficient or practical?

Comment: How big is the aquarium? What kind of blower is it (I'll try to look up stats on it).... I imagine it being too powerful, with a very high air intake and output amounts compared to an air pump, but the more info you can give on the leaf blower and your aquarium, the better answer you can get. I don't see it saving you much money unless you have EVERYTHING already. Let us know what you've got to work with

Comment: I'm a huge fan of DIY projects and the empowerment that comes with deconstructing economic production cycles (hobby carpenter and CC enthusiast), but when it comes to complex (sub)systems like pumps you easily risk to waste resources (e.g. for power) in the best case and to endanger people in the worst (even superficially simple systems undergo strict checks of independent authorities in most regions in most of the cases for a reason).

Answer (score 1):

No, aquarium pump  = 2 psi, blower << 0.1 psi. Pressure from the blower is too low by a couple orders of magnitude.

Comment: as this answer say using a leaf blower is wrong on so many levels(a leaf blower needs free flow of air for cooling or you will start a FIRE)and it makes a lot of sound and air suply have to be 24/7 for a fish tank.you can get airpumps with multiple outlets in the stores or they can order it for you.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, you simply don't. Depending on the species in your tank, you might not even need any extra air pump.

There are special diffusors for aquarium pumps so the clean water coming back into the tank will help increase the water surface (which is all the air pump does).

There are various variations, some letting the water sprinkle into the tank to take air with it (louder) or some work more like a paint spray gun (very silent, can work submerged as well).